# Can not deserialize instance of contactupload.User out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: android, json, jackson

I am parsing json response with jackson api ,I strucked with this exception please help me
I am new to jackson parsing.

json response:

```
[{"0":"96859","userid":"96859","1":"fshdh","phoneid":"fshdh","2":"","imageid":""},{"0":"67656656","userid":"67656656","1":"bdndjj","phoneid":"bdndjj","2":"","imageid":""},{"0":"6469895","userid":"6469895","1":"vzbdjn","phoneid":"vzbdjn","2":"","imageid":""},{"0":"6865665","userid":"6865665","1":"hdhdhh","phoneid":"hdhdhh","2":"","imageid":""}]
```

jackson parsing:

```
private User user;
    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    user=mapper.readValue(response, User.class);
```

Comment: Show your User class. And its a list. So you have to deserialize using Type reference of Collections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to read an array of Users:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User[] users = mapper.readValue(response, User[].class);
```